# How to get the content of this website to Excel with VBA and selectors?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest, queryselector

My problem with a website:

Although the data changes regularly, the structure of the data always remains the same. I try to transfer the content (only the last two columns with the headers: **Aktenzeichen** and **Aufgehoben**) to excel **in 3 columns (ID-Number, Date, Time)** by splitting the values of Aufgehoben in date and time.

My problem is that the values in "Bundesland" and "Amtsgericht" columns **(even though I don't need those)** have a different frequency of occurrence than the rest of the data and mess up all the trs and tds in the html-structure and so I don't understand how to use the selectors! Any ideas? THX.

my...mmm...code:

```
Sub GetData()

    Const URL = "https://www.zvg.com/appl/aufgehoben.prg?act=getHTML"
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elmt As Object
    Dim x As long

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
                   
     For x = 0 to ????.Length - 1
     Set elmt = html.querySelectorAll("???")
       ActiveSheet.Cells(y + 2, 2) = elmt.Item(?).innerText  'Aktenzeichen
       ActiveSheet.Cells(y + 2, 3) = elmt.Item(?).innerText  'Date
       ActiveSheet.Cells(y + 2, 4) = elmt.Item(?).innerText  'Time
     Next

End Sub
```

Comment: you can indeed go faster with css selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work with arrays, touch the sheet only at the end to reduce I/O, convert to using css selectors and doing your filtering within those selectors, use typed functions and reduce the code complexity.

---

**Results:**

Difference over 10,000 runs (single request, multiple parses and placing data in sheet).

[image]

Median difference was 5.4 times faster to make those changes over 10,000 runs.

No other difference in optimizations than described above. `ScreenUpdating` was switched off for both.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit

Public r As Long

Public Sub GetContents()
    
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.zvg.com/appl/aufgehoben.prg?act=getHTML", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim colOne As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, colTwoAndThree As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, i As Long
    
    Set colOne = html.querySelectorAll("td + td > table td + td:nth-child(2)")
    Set colTwoAndThree = html.querySelectorAll("td + td > table td + td:nth-child(3)")
    
    Dim headers() As Variant, results() As Variant
    
    headers = Array("ID-Number", "Date", "Time")
    ReDim results(1 To 1000, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
    
    With colOne
        
        For i = 0 To colOne.Length - 1
    
            UpdateResults results, colOne.Item(i).innerText, colTwoAndThree.Item(i).innerText

        Next
        
    End With

    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(headers) + 1, 1 To r)
    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateResults(ByRef results As Variant, ByVal col1 As String, ByVal col2And3 As String)
    Dim arrCol1() As String, arrCol2And3() As String
    Dim i As Long, datetime() As String
    
    arrCol1 = Split(col1, Chr$(10))
    arrCol2And3 = Split(col2And3, vbCrLf)
    
    For i = LBound(arrCol1) To UBound(arrCol1)
        r = r + 1
        results(r, 1) = Trim$(arrCol1(i))
        datetime = Split(arrCol2And3(i), Chr$(32))
        results(r, 2) = datetime(0): results(r, 3) = datetime(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

---

**Passing r as param in signature (rather than Public):**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetContents()
    
    Dim http As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60, html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    Set http = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60: Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    
    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.zvg.com/appl/aufgehoben.prg?act=getHTML", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim colOne As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, colTwoAndThree As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection, i As Long
    
    'Set colOne = html.querySelectorAll("td + td > table td + td:nth-child(2)")
    Set colOne = html.querySelectorAll("td td + td[style*='150']")
    'Set colTwoAndThree = html.querySelectorAll("td + td > table td + td:nth-child(3)")
    Set colTwoAndThree = html.querySelectorAll("td td + td[style*='150'] + td")
    
    Dim headers() As Variant, results() As Variant
    
    headers = Array("ID-Number", "Date", "Time")
    ReDim results(1 To 1000, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
    
    With colOne
        
        For i = 0 To colOne.Length - 1
    
            UpdateResults results, colOne.Item(i).innerText, colTwoAndThree.Item(i).innerText, r

        Next
        
    End With

    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(headers) + 1, 1 To r)
    results = Application.Transpose(results)
    
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub UpdateResults(ByRef results As Variant, ByVal col1 As String, ByVal col2And3 As String, ByRef r As Long)
    Dim arrCol1() As String, arrCol2And3() As String
    Dim i As Long, datetime() As String
    
    arrCol1 = Split(col1, Chr$(10))
    arrCol2And3 = Split(col2And3, vbCrLf)
    
    For i = LBound(arrCol1) To UBound(arrCol1)
        r = r + 1
        results(r, 1) = Trim$(arrCol1(i))
        datetime = Split(arrCol2And3(i), Chr$(32))
        results(r, 2) = datetime(0): results(r, 3) = datetime(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Haha QHarr, the person who's always answering my questions on stack overflow. Thanks for the modified code, there's a lot to learn from it.

Comment: @QHarr...somehow, the code doesn*t work. I get an error on `Set colOne = html.querySelectorAll("td + td > table td + td:nth-child(2)")` with INVALID ARGUMENT!?

Comment: What version of Excel are you running?

Comment: You can also use `Set colOne =  html.querySelectorAll("td td + td[style*='150']")`  and `Set colTwoAndThree =  html.querySelectorAll("td td + td[style*='150'] + td")`

Comment: I changed the code, now: `ReDim Preserve results(1 To UBound(headers) + 1, 1 To r)` = ERROR  Subscript out of range

Comment: Both versions work perfectly for me. Did you have public r  at the very top?

Comment: I added a second version for you at bottom with r as an argument to the second sub.

Comment: Oh...public r! I thought you had mistyped! Sorry :-)

Answer (score 3):

I can assure you there's probably a better answer than this, but the following code works:

```
Sub getStuff()

' Declare variables
Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim Table, Row, Data, Point As Variant
Dim i, x, j As Integer

' Make Request
With XMLPage
    .Open "GET", "https://www.zvg.com/appl/aufgehoben.prg?act=getHTML", False
    .send
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = .responseText
End With

' Set counters
i = 1
x = 0
j = 1

' Parse data into worksheet
For Each Table In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each Row In Table.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        For Each Data In Row.getElementsByTagName("td")
            ' Parse headers in first run
            If i = 1 Then
                Cells(i, j).Value = Data.innerText
            Else
                x = i
                ' Split the data points
                For Each Point In Split(Data.innerText, Chr(13))
                    Cells(i, j).Value = Point
                    i = i + 1
                Next Point
                If j <> 3 Then
                    i = x
                End If
            End If
            j = j + 1
        Next Data
    i = i + 1
    j = 1
    Next Row
Next Table

' Remove empty rows
Columns("C:C").Select
Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I appreciate it and will certainly use the code elsewhere. Unfortunately, the date and time are still in one column and not separated which is why I can't use it like this.